# Javascript use bitwise or equals operator |= for polyfill creation?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, operators, bit-manipulation, polyfills

Is there anything wrong with creating polyfills using [JavaScript's bitwise<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) or equals operator `|=`?

```
Date.now |= function() {
    return +new Date;
};
```

[<sup>1</sup>Bitwise operator reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)
[<sup>2</sup>`Date.now()` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: Did you even try this?

Comment: Yes, it dosen't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um, yes? There's a major difference between `|` and `||`, and polyfills should use:

```
Date.now = Date.now || function() {return +new Date;};
```

After all, if you used this:

```
Date.now = Date.now | function() {return +new Date;};
```

You'd get the result `0` overwriting the function.